# Is it possible to populate jstree using a loop?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, jstree

Hi I'd like to know if its possible to populate my jstree using a loop instead of hard-coding each node. Below is my code:

```
api.call("Get", {
   typeName: "Device"
}, function (result) {
   $('#jstree').jstree({
      'plugins': ["checkbox", "sort"],
      'core': {
         'data':
            [
               { id: result[0].id, text: result[0].name },
               { id: result[1].id, text: result[1].name }
            ]
        }
    });
});
```

I make an api call then populate my tree with the returned results. How can I format my JSON using a loop?

This is the main part I need to change:

```
[
   { id: result[0].id, text: result[0].name },
   { id: result[1].id, text: result[1].name }
]
```

This is what I've tried:

```
[
    function () {
       for(var i = 0; i < result.length; i++){
          { id: result[i].id, text: result[i].name }
       }
    }
]
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure.

```
api.call("Get", {
   typeName: "Device"
}, function (result) {
   $('#jstree').jstree({
      'plugins': ["checkbox", "sort"],
      'core': {
         'data': (function () {
           var results = [];
           for(var i = 0; i < result.length; i++){
             results.push({ id: result[i].id, text: result[i].name });
           }
           return results;
         })()
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Thank you so much. Worked after a minor fix. I changed your `var result = []` to `var results = []` because it was clearing the results returned by the api thus not entering the loop. So a different name helped. Then I changed `result.put` to `result.push` which then helped insert the values into the array.